# Why a floating point exception

Tags: c, exception

Just trying out some C on some of the project euler questions.

My question is why am I getting a floating point exception at run time on the following code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int sum;
int counter;

sum = 0;
counter = 0;

for (counter = 0; counter <= 1000; counter++)
{
    if (1000 % counter == 0) 
    {
        sum = sum + counter;
    }
}

printf("Hello World");
printf("The answer should be %d", sum);
}
```

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: What happens the first time in the loop, when `counter` is 0, and you divide by it to find the remainder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You start with counter = 0 and then do a "mod" with counter. This is a division by zero.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Bingo! Mike, please close your Q.

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing 1000 by zero on the first iteration (calculating a reminder of something divided by 0). Why it crashed with a floating-point exception... I don't know. Maybe the compiler translated it into a floating-point operation. Maybe just a quirk of the implementation.

Comment: I think the "floating point exception" message is operating system related. When the processor encounters a division by zero it executes a trap to the "divide by zero" handler of the system. Interestingly (and curiously), this handler on linux systems displays the "floating point exception" message.

Answer (score 1):

1000 % 0 is a division by zero

Answer (score 0):

What happens when `counter` is 0? You try to compute `1000 % 0`. You can't compute anything modulo 0, so you get an error.

Your if statement should read:

```
if (counter % 1000 == 0)
```

Comment: The only values for which counter % 1000 is 0 are 0 and 1000, so I'm not sure that the second part of your answer is correct? In fact, since the code appears to be finding and summing factors of 1000, I think the correction OP needs is "for ( counter = 1;"